# Visual Studio C++ NPAPI plugin with Twain support

Tags: c++, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012, npapi, twain

I want to make a Google Chrome plugin that use Twain to remote control a Digital Camera.
I want this to run on Windows and I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 C++.

I have [this](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-chrome-plugin-helloworld-example/) sample for NPAPI and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN) sample of CppWrapper for Twain which has 3 interesting files (TwainCpp.cpp TwainCpp.h twain.h)

Before doing anything, I want to merge these two projects.

- First step: putting twain.h in the npsimple project which failed, twain.h  errors caught.
- Second step: putting CppTwain in npsimple, which also failed because twain.h "contains" errors.

Problem is that when I create an empty project, and put twain.h in it, there is no error! So I tried to put npsimple files in that empty project, and this time I get error from npsimple files..

Error type : 
I have this code in twain.h :

```
#ifdef  _MSWIN_
typedef HANDLE TW_HANDLE; 
typedef LPVOID TW_MEMREF;
```

and I get plenty of errors like :

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'TW_HANDLE'
```

How can I merge these projects?

Comment: Could you add the actual errors you're encountering? I never heard of either of those projects, but I doubt anyone can help you without knowing what the actual errors are.

Answer (score 0):

`HANDLE` is an unspecified type because you don't include anything that is specificing it. You'll want to include `windows.h`.

Obviously there is no error when you add only the `twain.h` header file to the empty project - you haven't added any sources to compile, hence there can be no compilation errors.